# python connection with SQL server

Tags: python, pyodbc, sqlconnection

I used the `pyodbc` and `pypyodbc` python package to connect to SQL server.

Drivers used anyone of these `['SQL Server', 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0', 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server']`.

connection string :

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
'Server=aaa.database.windows.net;'
'DATABASE=DB_NAME;'
'UID=User_name;'
'PWD=password')
```

now I am getting error message like

```
DatabaseError: (u'28000', u"[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
```

But I can connect to the server through the SQL server management studio.

its on SQL Server Authentication, Not Windows Authentication.

Is this about python package and driver issue or DB issue??? how to solve?

Comment: Have not tried it, but according to https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-odbc-driver/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451101/retrieving-data-from-sql-using-pyodbc it seems your connection string might be wrong - are you sure the individual parameters should be separated into individual strings and not be __one whole string__?

Comment: yes... It is correct.. else It will throw invalid syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not driver issue, you can see the error message is `DatabaseError: Login failed for user`, it means this problem occurs if the user tries to log in with credentials that cannot be validated. I suspect you are login with your windows Authentication, if so, use `Trusted_Connection=yes` instead:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=aaa.database.windows.net;DATABASE=DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

For more details, please refer to [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43815104/python-pyodbc-connection-error/43820031#43820031) about the difference of `SQL Server Authentication modes`.

Comment: its SQL server's username and password.. using the SQL authentication

Answer (score 3):

You can add `Trusted_Connection=NO;` in your connection string after the password

Answer (score 1):

I see you have no `port` defined in your script.

The general way to connect to a server using pyodbc `${DBName}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPass}   ${DBHost}   ${DBPort}`, where `DBName` is your database name, `DBUser` is the username used to connect to it, `DBPass` is the password, `DBHost` is the URL of your database, and `DBPort` is the port you use to connect to your DB.

I use MS SQL so my port is `1433`, yours might be different.

I've had this issue just today, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem because of driver definition in your connection string. You may try with below.

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}; Server=aaa.database.windows.net; DATABASE=DB_NAME; UID=User_name; PWD=password')
```

Answer (score 1):

I applied your connection string and updated it with my server connections details and it worked fine.
Are you sure your are passing correct user name and password ? 
Login failed implies connection was established successfully, but authentication didn't pass.